# Cant create dynamic textboxes using Renderer2 in angular4

Tags: html, angular

i'm working on Angular 4 and creating textboxes dynamically by clicking on a button using Renderer2. I had tried it on a dummy project first and it works well but when i put the code in my real project it won't work and there is no error on console and i had checked that the function is triggering or not by putting console.log in it and function is triggering and message is showing in the console but textbox creating code is not working. Can anyone help me in this?

Type script function

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer2, private el: ElementRef ) { }

addfield()  {

  console.log('function triggered');
  const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  const input = this.renderer.createElement('input');

  this.renderer.appendChild(div, input);

  this.renderer.addClass(div, 'col-md-6');
  this.renderer.addClass(div, 'col-sm-6');
  this.renderer.addClass(div, 'col-xs-12');

  console.log('cross passes the code');
  this.renderer.addClass(input, 'form-control');
  this.renderer.addClass(input, 'col-md-7');
  this.renderer.addClass(input, 'col-xs-12');

}
```

Html code

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addfield()" >Add New Fiels +</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="textboxes"></div>
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addfield()" >Add New Fiels +</button>
```

//

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
}

addfield()  {
....
const textboxes = document.querySelector('#textboxes'); //to get element
this.renderer.addClass(textboxes , "col-md-6"); //this is for add class 
let divel= this.renderer.createElement('div'); //this is for create an element 
this.renderer.appendChild(textboxes, divel);   //this is for append a child element 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is absolutely fine, only issue is you are not appending dynamically created
>   elements to the ui

**Component :**

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer2, private el: ElementRef ) {}

addfield()  {
    ....
    const textboxes = document.getElementById('textboxes');
    this.renderer.appendChild(textboxes, div);
}
```

**Template :**

```
<div id="textboxes"></div>

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addfield()" >Add New Fiels +</button>
```

---

Here is the link to working demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

missing the following line to add dynamic textboxes `this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, div);`

```
addfield() {
    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const input = this.renderer.createElement('input');

    this.renderer.appendChild(div, input);
    this.renderer.addClass(div, 'col-md-6');
    this.renderer.addClass(div, 'col-sm-6');
    this.renderer.addClass(div, 'col-xs-12');

    this.renderer.addClass(input, 'form-control');
    this.renderer.addClass(input, 'col-md-7');
    this.renderer.addClass(input, 'col-xs-12');

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, div);
}
```